Excel Add-in Conflict with Multiple Workbooks
I've built a custom add-in for Excel using the Excel VSTO add-in project in Visual Studio (C#) to display external data from applications like Excel file paths. However, I'm encountering a strange issue. It seems to conflict with the Excel add-in items when opening two more Excel applications. Let me clarify with an example: Suppose I open the add-in in one Excel workbook named "Book1". The add-in contains textboxes to store Excel file path data. Fore open another instance now if I open another Excel workbook named "Book2", initially the textboxes are loaded with values from "Book1." How can I resolve the issue
namespace ExcelAddIn2
{
    public partial class Ribbon1
    {        
        private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {
            editBox1.Text = "";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
            fd.Title = "Open Excel SpreadSheet";
            fd.Filter = "Excel Worksheets (.xlsx files)|*.xlsx| Excel Worksheets(*.xlsm files)|*.xlsm";
            if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                editBox1.Text = fd.FileName.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
} 



